# JBoss 7.0.1 xa-datasource exception. javax.transaction.xa.XAException

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I use two separate datasources. Using EJB3.0 I was using `non-Xa-datasources`. I have error something like this :`could not open connection`, `state-aware object`. this was , because In one `stateless bean` I was calling second `stateless bean`'s method, which was connected diferent database. 
Then I change `datasources structure` and change it to `xa-datasources` like this:

```
<datasources>
            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/ooo" pool-name="ooo" enabled="true" use-java-       context="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx:orcl
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                 </security>
            </xa-datasource>
            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/mysqlds" pool-name="mysqlds" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                    jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                </security>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Therefore I have some error in startup jboss, and I put `mysql module.xml` this (`dependency> javax.transaction.api.`):

```
<dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>    
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>  
</dependencies>
```

Everything works fine but, there is `warning` every 2 minutes:

```
 11:00:16,213 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA016027: Local XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery got XA exception XAException.XAER_RMERR: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.recover(OracleXAResource.java:709)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection.recover(XAManagedConnection.java:358)
at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceWrapperImpl.recover(XAResourceWrapperImpl.java:162)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.xaRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:503) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:471) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.bottomUpRecovery(XARecoveryModule.java:385) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkSecondPass(XARecoveryModule.java:166) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:789) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar:]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem. 
Problem was `user`. this user I using another application, that are running already.
I created new `user` , and everything works fine